# How to use permissions with Laravel API and Calling Application

Tags: laravel, permissions

I have setup an API in Laravel using Passport for authentication and spatie/laravel-permission to add permission functionality. I also have a calling application, again written in Laravel. I can authenticate from the calling app to the api but how do i ensure that the calling app knows the permissions available? What should the user/roles/permissions tables look like at the api and in the calling app?
Essentially i would like to use code like: $user->can('do something') in both applications.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the Spatie package is that it allows you to make such code calls as `$user->can('do something')`, and reading the Github page it looks like it creates tables default named "role" and "permission" when you run the Migration after installing the package. In other words it's a matter of configuring the models and database connections in both of your apps correctly, specifically the User Model and the Permission table for both apps.

To clarify, I think you are asking these questions:

1. how can a second app know what permissions are available,
2. how would you be able to use something like "$user->can('do something')" in BOTH applications, touching the exact same data.

Answers:

1. If the "permission" and "role" tables already exist, then if your API doesn't have some endpoint to ask for the roles or permissions already available, you'd define a new one. For instance, some API call that asks the Permission table "getPermissions" or something and that your second application can call -- it either has to ask the database itself (via the API), or it has to get that from the second application. *Which depends on how your two applications interact with each other*
2. you would have to make sure to configure the second application so that the "User" model refers to the same table as the table the first application uses for the User model. Essentially, the model is being used as an interface to the table, so if both applications have a defined User model that references the same table and both are configured to connect to the same database that table is in, Laravel's user model will "just know" the data in question (this is the basis of Laravel's Eloquent for Models).

Additionally, for what it's worth, I haven't used the spatie/laravel-permission package, but in relation to question #1 I did find a function in the docs that might also be used to grab currently made permissions in list form from a "permission table":

[Permission Model, getPermissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Models/Permission.php)

And for reference, about Laravel's Eloquent and Models (which may be something you already know, but I'll leave this link anyway):

[Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)